# How to detect if in a project, then configure another key binding for Projectile?

Tags: projectile

I have a key binding that's bounded to `helm-for-files`.

`(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<f9>") 'helm-for-files)`

But when I enter a directory which is a project (to being recognized with `.projectile` file), then I would like to change the key binding to the following:

`(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<f9>") 'helm-projectile)`.

But when I enter another directory without any project files, then revert back to the default `helm-for-files` key binding.

I looked if there a hook for Projectile exists, but there isn't any hook available. Any other suggestions, to detect if I'm currently in a Projectile directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```el
(defun contextual-f9 ()
  (if (projectile-project-p) ;; detect if current buffer is in a project
      (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<f9>") 'helm-projectile)
    (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<f9>") 'helm-for-files)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'contextual-f9)
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook #'contextual-f9)
(add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook #'contextual-f9)
```

With `window-configuration-change-hook`, it is possible to update the keymap if you change window configuration, since it is always the case if you use Helm to switch buffer.

Another simpler solution is that you can just use `helm-for-files`, but add Helm Projectile sources to `helm-for-files-preferred-list`:

```el
(add-to-list 'helm-for-files-preferred-list helm-source-projectile-projects)
(add-to-list 'helm-for-files-preferred-list helm-source-projectile-files-list)
(add-to-list 'helm-for-files-preferred-list helm-source-projectile-directories-list)
```

When not in a project, you will get a normal `helm-find-files` and when in a project, you get candidates from Helm Projectile.

Comment: Thanks Tu Do, it works, but not completely. When I switch back to a buffer, which is not in a project, I still got `helm-projectile` when pressing `<f9>`?
I'm asking it, because `helm-for-files-preffered-list` will not work with projectile sources if I'm not inside a project.

Comment: @ReneFrogertjuh yes, Helm Projectile should not work when you are outside of a project. That's the intended behaviour, since projectile is used for navigating a project.

Comment: Or, are you getting some error from Helm Projectile that prevents you from running `helm-for-files`? **EDIT**: I updated the answer to use `window-configuration-change-hook`. With that hook, it should work when you switch buffer with Helm.

Comment: I agree with your comments and edits, thanks for your addition. Integrate projectile-sources into `helm-for-files` would be ideal. But I wonder why I can't add `helm-source-projectile-buffer-list`, hence my question to switch the keybindings.

Comment: @ReneFrogertjuh how do you add? Btw, did the edit solve the problem for you?

Comment: I add it like this:  http://pastebin.com/U47gNBd1 , every source works fine, even in non-project directories, except `helm-source-projectile-buffer-list`. I tried your edit, but I prefer my solution, because it allows you to order your sources list in `helm-for-files` more consistently.

Answer (score 8):

Actually you can do it by using a wrapper of those two functions:

```
(defun smart-for-files ()
  "Call `helm-projectile' if `projectile-project-p', otherwise
fallback to `helm-for-files'."
  (interactive)
  (if (projectile-project-p)
      (helm-projectile)
    (helm-for-files)))
```

then set the keybinding as you want:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<f9>") 'smart-for-files)
```